# The method setNativeSource() expects android.graphics.Bitmap instance

Tags: android, typescript, nativescript

In my application, if I choose an image from the gallery, I have to be redirected to a modal window with that image. The problem is that the image is downloaded from the service to the component, but is not displayed, instead I have an error message.

**The component from which I send my request to the gallery:**

```
        const imageAsset = await this.gallery.selectPhoto();
        this.rediresct("loading");
        const options: ModalDialogOptions = {
            context: imageAsset,
            viewContainerRef: this.vref,
            fullscreen: false
        };
        setTimeout(async () => {
            const response = await this.modal.showModal(
                ConfirmImageComponent,
                options
            );
            if (response == "success") {
            }
        });
    }
```

**Service:**

```
    
    source: any;
    constructor() {}
    async selectPhoto(): Promise<Array<any>> {
        let context = imagepicker.create({
            mode: "single"
        });
        await context.authorize();
        let imageAsset = [];
        const selection = await context.present();
      

        imageAsset = selection;
        return imageAsset;
    }
}
```

**The component that downloads the image from the service and has to display it:**

```
    obraz: ImageAsset;
    constructor(
        private gallery: GalleryService,
        private params: ModalDialogParams
    ) {
        this.image = params.context;

        var pict = new Image();
        pict.src = this.image;
        console.log(pict.src);
    }

    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

In last code I use console log to display selected image source and it works, but image is not displayed. In VS Code I see this error:
[image: The image source is displayed, but the program continues to end up with an error]

Comment: `selection` must be an array, try `imageAsset = selection[0]`

Comment: @Manoj it works, but in this construction `imageAsset = selection[0]` I see an error :  _TS2740: Type 'ImageAsset' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 25 more._ How can I get rid of it? Over `constructor(){}` I added `imageAsset = []` but error still exist.

Comment: Change the return type, put only any instead of any within array type.

Comment: When I change return type : ` async selectPhoto(): Promise<Array<any>>` to ` async selectPhoto(): Promise<any>` app not work and return the same error.

Comment: Please share a Playground Sample.

Comment: @Manoj https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=endIXT

Comment: Please make sure the Playground is right, it's completely broken.

Comment: @Manoj https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=vkpsJ2  this is good Playground Sample

Comment: You want to select & show multiple images Or just one?

Comment: @Manoj I want select & show just one image

Comment: Then just declare variable as any not array. I will update the Playground when I get a chance.

Comment: Okay. I'll wait, and in the meantime, I'll try to improve things myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return a single asset you could just do,

```
async selectPhoto(): Promise<any> {
    let context = imagepicker.create({
        mode: "single"
    });
    await context.authorize();
    const selection = await context.present();
    return selection[0];
}
```

Make sure you catch the errors from select photo.